# Duplicate values over months between two dates SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with data in the format below

```
Account_number  Start_date  End_date    
1               20/03/2017  09/07/2018  
2               15/12/2017  08/12/2018  
3               01/03/2017  01/03/2017
```

I would like the result below

```
Account_number  Start_date  End_date    Balance_date
1               20/03/2017   9/07/2018  31/03/2017
1               15/12/2017  08/12/2018  30/04/2017
1               01/03/2017  01/03/2017  31/05/2017
1           
1           
1               20/03/2017  09/07/2018  09/07/2018
```

and this replicated for all other account_numbers
The balance date should be the last day of each month between the start_date and the end_date

I am using this query:

```
select
  account_number,
  start_date, 
  end_DATE, 
  last_day(TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS( START_DATE, LEVEL-1 ) )) as balance_date
from table
connect by level <= ceil(months_between(
                       (start_date),
                       (end_date)) )
*                      + 1;
```

But the dates don't seem to be correct

Comment: What is the database you use?

Comment: please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind your question.  last day of each month between start date and end date.  This indicate, 16 lines (march 2017 to june 2018) only for the first row. (20/03/2017 to 09/07/2018).

Comment: @DanielBlais, last day of each month for all the months between the start_day and the last_day.

Comment: Your expected result is very confusing.

Comment: I fail to understand the rules you used to get to the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the other users have mentioned, the expected result is not super clear but I think I got the just of what you're asking. I also don't know what database you're using but I know how to do this in postgresql using generate series and some date manipulation. This is probably not easily portable to databases outside of postgres.

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
account_number INTEGER, start_date DATE, end_date DATE
)

INSERT INTO foo VALUES
(1, '2017-03-20','2018-07-09'),
(2, '2017-12-15','2018-12-08'),
(3, '2017-03-01','2017-03-01')

WITH q1 AS(
select
  account_number,
  start_date, 
  end_DATE,
  generate_series(start_date, end_date, '1 day') AS day_interval
from foo
)
SELECT account_number, start_date, end_date,day_interval, date_trunc('month', day_interval + INTERVAL '1 month') - INTERVAL '1 day' balance_date
FROM q1
```

Returns data like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fq4i.png)
And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an8KB.png)